# Problem adding validation list in excel sheet using VBA

Tags: validation, vba, list, addition

I have an excel sheet that is loaded with a dynamic result set of data. I need to add a YES/NO dropdown at the end of each row once all the data is loaded. I have to do this dynamically as I do not know the size of the result set beforehand.
The following code throws an 'Applicaton-defined or object-defined error':

```
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim VOptions As String
VOptions = "1. Yes, 2. No"

firstRow = GetResultRowStart.row + 1
lastRow = GetResultRowStart.End(xlDown).row

For I = firstRow To lastRow

Range("AO" & firstRow & ":AO" & lastRow).Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=VOptions
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "Options"
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Click yes or no"
    .errorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With


 Next I
```

The method GetResultRowStart gives me the row starting which result data is populated in the sheet. I have used this method elsewhere in some other part of the code too and it works perfectly.
Debugging using message boxes suggested error being thrown at the Range(..).select statement.

Any ideas about the cause of this error.

Comment: What is the purpose of the For I = firstRow to lastRow loop? It seems that every cell in the column has the same validation so you should only need to add the validation once to the entire selection

Comment: Thats because there is more stuff being done inside the loop.However the problem persists even when the validation list code is outside the loop for a specific cell like this..
Range("AO11").Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=VOptions
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "Options"
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Click yes or no"
    .errorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final thoughts on this one :

Setting the SetFocusOnClick property of every button in the workbook to false seems to have done the trick (atleast for now). 
But if this is a required condition, it shouldn't have worked at all with the value set as true. However , it sometimes did.
But this is the dependable solution I found.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this problem for 2 days! Cheers

Comment: Nice! This helped me too. Just one thing: it's called `TakeFocusOnClick` in my Excel 2003...

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to channel my inner-Spolsky here:

If you're referring to a range not on the `ActiveSheet` you should **fully qualify the reference**.

Something like the following should work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mysheet").Range("AO" & firstRow & ":AO" & lastRow).Select
```

Comment: :-)
Well.. there is a Me.Unprotect followed by a Me.Activate call right before this bit of code.
However, I did try a qualified reference.Ended up with a "Subscript out of range " error at the same line.

Wondering why...? 'cause this code is in a public subroutine in  "mysheet"

Comment: Ok Adam...this has confused me...tell me if this makes sense...
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mysheet").Range("AO" & firstRow & ":AO" & lastRow).Select gave a Subscript out of range error.
However, what did work was 
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AO" & firstRow & ":AO" & lastRow)

and the list is indeed created in 'mysheet'
Can you please explain that...?

Comment: "Subscript out of range" here usually suggests that the worksheet is not called what you think it's called. Could there be a trailing space, for example? I've caught myself out with that one.

Comment: This problem is baffling me more 'n more. Now at this line ,
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=VOptions
it says,
Runtime error -2147417848 (80010108) 
Automation error.The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

What I find weirder is that when I debug, it proceeds smoothly without error and adds a validation list in the column at the end of it.

Comment: @atlantis:  for the first problem you were having, try using the sheet *index* instead of the name, e.g. ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("AO" & firstRow & ":AO" & lastRow).Select

Comment: @atlantis:  for your second error, you might find this link helpful:  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q319832

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the link... I have seen this link before and have added more qualified references everywhere I could think of.
The problem, as I said below, seems to lie in the .Add method on the Validation object.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem, "automation error". What I did was activate the sheet that I was going to put the validation list in and the error just disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i used was to unprotect the worksheet before With xx.validation and then protect if afterwards.  [I didn't have to do this in Excel 2000 and I think i didn't have to do it in Excel 2003 until maybe a service pack was added though can't say 100%.]

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced a very similar problem in Excel. I found the code to programmatically set the validation dropdown worked fine when I ran it in the immediate window, but didn't work when called from a button on the worksheet. I've now realised it's because the button had the focus, and no amount of trying to select or activate the sheet or cell in the code prior to setting the validation seemed to fix this. However, I've just realised there is a 'TakefocusOnClick' property of buttons in Excel, which is set to True by default. By setting this to False, the button never gets the focus, and hey presto, my code to set validation now works fine.

It might not be the answer to everyone's validation problems, but I hope there might just be somebody who can benefit from the above.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on the "Method 'Add' of object 'Validation' failed" error.  Here are the possible causes and how to resolve them:

1. ***Protected worksheet***: The sheet on which the data validation is being added can’t be protected, even if the cells to which the validation is being added are not **Locked** and even if the protection mode is **UserInterfaceOnly**.  You must fully unprotect the sheet, add the validation, and then re-protect the sheet.
2. ***Loss of focus by the worksheet cell range***: If focus has been taken by any control on the active worksheet (usually a command button) that has been previously clicked by the user, this error will be triggered when the **Validation.Add** method is subsequently called.  (Really, it’s true!)  This applies, especially, to any command button that executes the code that adds the validation but it also applies to any control on the worksheet that could be clicked prior to execution of that code.  Since there seems to be no legitimate connection between the focus state and the addition of data validation to a cell or range, I consider this an Excel bug.  Here are the workarounds:

   **A.** *Prevent loss of focus by the worksheet’s cell range*: Set the **TakeFocusOnClick** property of all controls on the worksheet to **False**.

   **B.** *Retrieve focus to the worksheet’s cell range*: In the VBA code, prior to executing the **Validation.Add** method, call the **Select** method of any cell on the worksheet.  The logical choice is to select the cell or range to which data validation is being added, but any cell will do.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to get rid of Selection object. It is best suited for Macro Recorder :)

btw in your loop each time you are selecting the same block again and again, even if you are doing some more processing on it, consider selecting the block being worked on in each iteration or remove the whole loop.

Can you try this after you for loop?

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AO" & firstRow & ":AO" & lastRow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=VOptions
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "Options"
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Click yes or no"
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Been there done that Adarsha. Still threw an automation error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the error was related to the setting of Application.ReferenceStyle

See corrected code below-

```
If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1 Then
  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=R1C16:R" & foldercnt & "C16"
Else
  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=$P1:$P" & foldercnt
End If
```