# COMException (0x80010108 - RPC_E_DISCONNECTED) When Closing Excel.Workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop, com-interop, excel-interop

When I run the following code, I get the exception below:

```
''# NOTE: ExcelApp is a Private main form variable
Dim ReportBooks As Excel.Workbooks = ExcelApp.Workbooks
Dim ReportBook As Excel.Workbook = ReportBooks.Open(localFilename)
Dim ReportSheet As Excel.Worksheet = ReportBook.Sheets("Report")

''# Retreive data from sheet

ReleaseCOM(ReportSheet)
ReportBook.Close(True) ''# Error raised here
ReleaseCOM(ReportBook)
ReleaseCOM(ReportBooks)
```

> ```
> ERROR:
> COMException was unhandled
> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
> ```

Note:  All data appears to have been retreived correctly.

Please help me diagnose and overcome this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RPC_DISCONNECTED...the dreaded "*The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.*" issue. There are a ton of causes to this, looks like you've covered the global variables issue with `Excel.`. Can you put the first `ReleaseCOM(ReportSheet)` below `ReportBook(Close)` and run it? Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994573/problem-adding-validation-list-in-excel-sheet-using-vba).

Comment: Unfortunately, swapping the line causing the error and the line before had no effect. The program still crashes when trying to close the sheet.

Comment: Man, sorry to hear this. I dealt with this issue a few times and it was always like sorcery to get it to work. The main issue here is that by the time you get to `ReportBook.Close(True)` Excel is no longer managing ReportBook - something is releasing it - hence the error. Have you tried a code step through with debug adding a watch to ReportBook?

Comment: Got it!  Code stepping worked.  My code accidentally opened the same file twice and closed it twice (well once then crashed when closing a second time).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to hear this. That particular error is really frustrating, so it's great that you got things worked out!

Comment: Exactly! There were several calls to the same code which included close operation.