# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010108) when creating an instance of Excel in vb.net 3.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, office-interop, excel-interop

So, I have a program that launches an instance of Excel. It works on my machine as well as the machines of 2 others, but when my project leader tries it, he gets the following error:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010108): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010108.
```

The code below is where I'm creating the excel instance and launching it.

```
    Dim xlsApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsWS As Excel.Worksheet

    Try
        If ugLoadDeviationsDetails.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then

            'Creates a temporary excel file with data located in the grid
            UltraGridExcelExporter1.Export(ugLoadDeviationsDetails, "C:\ProgramData\Data-Tronics\ShellFiles\LoadDeviations\tempExcel")

            xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\ProgramData\Data-Tronics\ShellFiles\LoadDeviations\tempExcel")

            xlsWS = DirectCast(xlsWB.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
            DirectCast(xlsWS.Cells.EntireRow, Excel.Range).ClearFormats()
            DirectCast(DirectCast(xlsWS.Cells("1", "A"), Excel.Range).EntireRow().Cells, Excel.Range).Interior.Color = Color.LightGray.ToArgb

            DirectCast(xlsWS, Excel.Worksheet).Copy()

            xlsWB.Close(False)

            xlsApp.Visible = True
            xlsApp.UserControl = True

        Else
            RaiseEvent ShowError("Cannot write file when grid is empty.")
        End If 
    Catch ex As Exception

        For Each wb As Excel.Workbook In xlsApp.Workbooks
            wb.Close(False)
        Next
        xlsApp.Quit()
    Finally
        xlsApp = Nothing
        xlsWB = Nothing
        xlsWS = Nothing
    End Try
```

According to the stacktrace it breaks on the following line:

```
    Dim xlsApp As New Excel.Application
```

The project lead uses the exact same version of Excel as I do (2010), can anyone think of any reason as to why this may occur, and how I may fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [COMException (0x80010108 - RPC\_E\_DISCONNECTED) When Closing Excel.Workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421188/comexception-0x80010108-rpc-e-disconnected-when-closing-excel-workbook)

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't think so since it happens when creating a new Excel.Application for the first time, and so far only on the one machine (which happens to be a two day drive away).

Comment: Excel started up but then immediately terminated again without saying goodbye nicely.  Something is drastically wrong with it, the kind of problem that makes you re-install Office.

Comment: @HansPassant This is what we are currently doing. We've shown that it work on 4-5 other machines, so this is the most likely cause. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add
xlsSheet = xlsBook.Worksheets.Add
```