# Setting DOM Element using JS replaces webpage body with value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, autohotkey

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here...

1.) Navigate to google.

2.) In the address bar (Internet Explorer) type

```
javascript: document.all.q.value = "Hello Google"
```

Other knowledge I have learnt from elsewhere implies that the Input Element of the Google site **should** be filled with "Hello Google".

However to the contrary, for me, a completely blank page opens, completely blank except for the words "Hello Google":

```
<html>
    <head>
        <tile></title>
    </head>
    <body>Hello Google</body>
</html>
```

Weird? But hey, I thought, perhaps that's just because of the syntax... So I tried using getElementById() instead:

```
javascript: document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "Hello Google"
```

Guess what? The same "Hello Google" webpage as before...

What is up with this? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Example of using IE COM Object to manipulate Google Search page:

```
pwb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") ; Create our Object, pwb holds this reference.
pwb.Visible := True ; Set our page as visible
pwb.Navigate("http://google.com") ; Navigate to our website
while pwb.busy or pwb.ReadyState != 4 ;Wait for page to load
   Sleep 10
pwb.document.getElementByID("lst-ib").Value := ("Ahk IE COM Objects")
sleep 1000
pwb.document.forms[0].submit()
```

Comment: Does that actually work for you? :O When I run the same code and navigate to google, IE object's reference changes and thus I cannot interact with it anymore...

Comment: It does work for me: Win 10, AutoHotkey Version 1.1.24 here's a video of it running: https://sendvid.com/nid7aa7u

Comment: Huh... Perhaps that's something to do with our IT security at work then... Thanks for the code though! Will be very useful! :)

Comment: Well I tried the AHK Script today. It returned the error `Error:  0x80010108 - The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.` Full error message: http://pastebin.com/qWyyga44

Comment: It's apparent now there is a problem with your computer and not with the code. Look here for a solution to your COM issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421188/comexception-0x80010108-rpc-e-disconnected-when-closing-excel-workbook

Comment: Have you tried running the script as Administrator?